# ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree while doing ng new

Tags: angular, angular-cli

[When I try to create new project using ng new, I am getting this error. I tried clearing catche, reinstalling angular cli and node, updated everything still the error is there.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3tBzm.png)

Comment: ng new <name> --force

Comment: No effect, same error occured again

Answer (score 0):

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

update or new install @angular/cli

Comment: Already tried updating as well as reinstalling. No effect